# gambler's ruin with unequal bet

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Like all existing gamble's ruin problem, assume P(i) represents the probability that the gambler wins N dollars given that his current wealth is i dollars (he has i dollars at the moment). In most of the existing solutions, it is assumed that the gambler bets on 1 dollars. It means, if the gambler wins the current step, his state is changed to (i+1) and if he loses, the state is changed to (i-1). In this case, P(i) is calculated using the iterative equation below:
P(i+1) - P(i) = (q/p)(P(i) - P(i-1)) where p is the probability of winning in each single game and q = 1-p. Moreover, P(0) = 0 and P(N) = 1

Here I have a little different assumption. In a single gamble, assume the gambler wins 2 dollars with the probability of p and loses 1 dollar with the probability of q = 1-p (I just changed the bet in case he wins). In this especial case, if the gambler wins, then the current state i is changed to i+2. If the gambler loses, the current state is changed to i-1.

Does anybody know how to calculate P(i) in such an especial case?
I have tried the mentioned iterative equation like below:
P(i+2) - P(i) = (q/p)(P(i) - P(i-1))
But I cannot achieve a general solution for P(i). The result through the iterative method will be quite complicated.
Using the iterative solution, you should calculate P(i) according to P(i-1). Then, since P(0) = 0, P(1) is calculated easily and other P(i) would be appeared. But, I could not find a general equation to calculate P(i) directly.
Please note that P(N+1) = P(N) = 1 and P(0) = 0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply an ordinary homogeneous linear recurrence

$$ P(i+2) = \frac{1}{p} P(i) - \frac{q}{p} P(i-1)$$

which can be solved with standard methods. Every solution to this will be a linear combination of the three basis solutions of the form

$$ P(n) = r^n $$

which we can plugin to the recurrence

$$ r^{i+2} = \frac{1}{p} r^i - \frac{q}{p} r^{i-1} $$
$$ r^3 - \frac{1}{p} r + \frac{q}{p} = 0 $$

and solve for the three possible values for $r$. (If this equation has repeated roots, then there will be basis solutions of different forms)

Note that $r=1$ is one of the three solutions, so after dividing out $r-1$ you only need to use the quadratic formula to get the other roots.

[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20f(n%2B2)%20%3D%201%2Fp%20f(n)%20-%20(1-p)%2Fp%20f(n-1)%20and%20f(0)%3D0%20%20for%20f) gives the general form. (I was only able to figure out how to specify the boundary condition at zero)

---

Incidentally, you could alternatively solve this by repeating the trick you used. Writing $D(n) = P(n) - P(n-1)$, the recurrence you wrote becomes

$$ D(n+2) + D(n+1) = \frac{q}{p} D(n) $$

Then, writing $E(n) = D(n) - u D(n-1)$ for an unspecified $u$, we get

$$ E(n+2) + u D(n+1) + E(n+1) + u D(n) = \frac{q}{p} D(n) $$
$$ E(n+2) + u E(n+1) + u^2 D(n) + E(n+1) + u D(n) = \frac{q}{p} D(n) $$

so if we pick $u$ such that $u^2 + u = \frac{q}{p}$, the equation becomes
$$ E(n+2) + (u+1) E(n+1) = 0 $$
whose general form is easily solved for.

Comment: That's cool. If P(n) = $r^n$, then what about P(0). Acording to what you described, P(0) = $r^0$ = 1 but it is 0.

Comment: @AbbasArghavani: The general solution is a linear combination of the basis solutions. You have three coefficients and three boundary conditions; you have to solve the system of three linear equations if you want the solution satisfying the boundary conditions.